# Arreglar un problema con las librerías en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Básicamente estoy empezando a aprender a como usar android studio, y me salio el error de la imagen
[image: Error]
Este error evita que la app funcione o inicializa al probarla con los emuladores, creo que el error se debe a un ChipGroup y Chips.

[image: Causa]

debido a que intente sacandolos y el error desaparece

Dato quiza importante : Cambie la direccion donde se almacenan por defecto los proyectos
Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Considera agregar el build.gradle, que targetSDK estas usando, en que dispositivo de que sistema operativo se muestra el problema, este problema esta relacionado a el SDK que usas.

Comment: Estoy en windows 10, el SDK es el Api16: Android 4.1(Jelly Bean), y tambien al crear un proyecto nuevo me sale esta advertencia "projet location should not contain whitespace, as this can cause problems with the NDK tools", y pues en la carpeta donde lo guardo hay espacio

Comment: "This operation requires the library com.google.android.material:material:+.

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
-   androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4@aar
and:
-   androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4@aar

With the dependency:
-   androidx.annotation:*:2.0.0
versus:
-   androidx.annotation:*:1.1.0

The project may not compile after adding this library.
Would you like to add it anyway?"

Comment: Tambien me sale ese error :c o esa advertencia al intentar añadir la libreria que necesito